# aligning 2 of 3 elements in a nav to the right and another to the left

Tags: css, html

I want to create a full width nav with the page logo on the left that is a link and links home.  There is also a register/login and cart li element.

I would like to put a background color 100% on the screen also.  They also need to be inline.

Using HTML5 tags how can you semantically do this.  What is the heirarchy of elements?

How would you achieve this.

### CSS

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0;
}
header h1{
     margin: 0;
    padding: .5em 0;
    color: black;
    clear:both;
}
header li:nth-child(1){
    float: left;
}

header li:nth-child(n+2){
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

### header

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <!-- the head section -->
    <head>
        <title>Willie's Fishing Supply</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="<?php echo $app_path ?>main.css" />
    </head>

    <!-- the body section -->
    <body>
        <header>

                <ul id="leftUpperNav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $app_path; ?>">
                            <h1>Willie's Fishing Supply</h1>
                        </a>
                    </li></ul>
                    <?php
                    // Check if user is logged in and
                    // display appropriate account links
                    $account_url = $app_path . 'account';
                    $logout_url = $account_url . '?action=logout';
                    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) :
                    ?>
            <ul id="rightUpperNav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $account_url; ?>">My Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $logout_url; ?>">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $account_url; ?>">Login/Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $app_path . 'cart'; ?>">Cart</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <nav>


    <ul>




        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <!-- display links for all categories -->
        <?php
            require_once('model/database.php');
            require_once('model/category_db.php');

            $categories = get_categories();
            foreach($categories as $category) :
                $name = $category['categoryName'];
                $id = $category['categoryID'];
                $url = $app_path . 'catalog?category_id=' . $id;
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
               <?php echo $name; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <h2>Temp Link</h2>
        <li>
            <!-- These links are for testing only.
                 Remove them from a production application. -->
            <a href="<?php echo $app_path; ?>admin">Admin</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>


        </header>
   <section id = "wrapper">
```

Comment: To the right, and to the left... of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just float some elements left and some right to achieve this.

### HTML

```
<header class="global-header">
    <div class="inner-w">

        <a href="#" class="site-logo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
        </a>

        <nav class="account-nav">
            <a href="#">login</a>
            <a href="#">whatever</a>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>
```

### CSS

```
.global-header {
    background: #f06;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.global-header .inner-w {
    max-width: 700px; /* or 960 or whatever */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.global-header .site-logo {
    float: left;
}

.account-nav {
    float: right;
}

.account-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

and here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fSnbD/) (which in the future is a good place for you to start - and to show other users what you've tried so far)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...Just a question but what if you wanted to put a main navigation against that navigation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I entirely understand your question. From what I understood, you're trying to make a navbar for the top of a webpage, and you'd like it to have a linking logo and a few list elements.

Based on that assumption, I'd highly recommend checking out Bootstrap. Bootstrap is a front-end framework made by Twitter for making elegant, responsive web projects. Start by checking out the docs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). The docs include the example below, which is a navbar with just about anything you could ever reasonably want in a navbar. NOTE that you DO need to add the bootstrap script to your page if you want to use Bootstrap components. Check out their ["Getting Started" page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for more info.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```